# Minimax algorithm for tic tac toe goes into endless recursive loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

**Problem :**
 The Minimax function that I wrote completes the first tree, where it fills out all possible slots of a Tic Tac Toe board, but then the score starts returning the infinite value I had set.

**Hints :**
 The Recursion starts to go bad as soon as the board is filled out completely the first time and then it tries to empty the board tracking back, but gets stuck after emptying the last three slots, where it gets into an endless loop. The returning value is infinity, both negative and positive. Somehow, the board isn't emptied and thus values aren't changed.

**Some Info :**
 I am building the project in Unity C#, the array data structure I use is a struct type for storing information of the board.

```
//The initial function that returns the optimal move for AI to execute.
    public int[] GetMove()
    {
        int aBestScore = -mInfinity;
        int[] aMoveInfo = new int[2];

        SyncValues();
        int aLength = mAIPosInfo.GetLength(0);
        mBreakPoint = mBreakLimit;
        int aTest = -1;

        //Initial loop that tests the first move and gets into the recursion
        for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < aLength; j++)
            {
                aTest++;
                if (mAIPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece == PieceId.Empty)
                { 
                    mAIPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece = mAIPiece;

                    int aScore = MiniMax(mAIPosInfo, 0, 0, 0, false, i, j);
                    mAIPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece = PieceId.Empty;

                    if (aScore > aBestScore)
                    {
                        aBestScore = aScore;
                        aMoveInfo[0] = i;
                        aMoveInfo[1] = j;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return aMoveInfo;
    }

//The MINI MAX ALGORITHM
    private int MiniMax(AIPosInfo[,] pPosInfo, int pDepth, bool pMaximizingPlayer, int pRowId, int pColId)
    {

        int aScore = CheckScore(pMaximizingPlayer, pPosInfo, pRowId, pColId);

        if (pDepth >= mDepthLimit || aScore != -5) //-5 is value returned for still playing
        {
            return aScore;
        }

    //Maximizing player turn..the AI Turn!!!
        if (pMaximizingPlayer)
        {
            int aMaxEval = -mInfinity;
            int aLength = pPosInfo.GetLength(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < aLength; j++)
                {
                    if (pPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece == PieceId.Empty)
                    {                        
                        pPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece = mAIPiece;

                        int aEvalve = MiniMax(pPosInfo, pDepth + 1, false, i, j);

                        pPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece = PieceId.Empty;

                        aMaxEval = Mathf.Max(aEvalve, aMaxEval);


                    }
                }
            }            
                return aMaxEval;           
        }
        else   //THE HUMAN PLAYER'S TURN
        {
            int aLength = pPosInfo.GetLength(0);
            int aMinEval = mInfinity;

            for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < aLength; j++)
                {
                    if (pPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece == PieceId.Empty)
                    {


                        pPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece = mHumanPiece;


                        int aEval = MiniMax(pPosInfo, pDepth + 1, true, i, j);

                        pPosInfo[i, j].mFilledPiece = PieceId.Empty;

                        aMinEval = Mathf.Min(aEval, aMinEval);


                    }

                }
            }          
            return aMinEval;

            }
}
```

The CheckScore and CheckWin functionality, the dictionary has this info

```
    mScoreInfo.Add(PieceId.Cross, 1); //AI
    mScoreInfo.Add(PieceId.Zero, -1); //Human
    mScoreInfo.Add(PieceId.Draw, 0);
    mScoreInfo.Add(PieceId.Playing, -5);



private int CheckScore(bool pMaximizing, AIPosInfo[,] pPosInfo, int pRowId, int pColId)
    {
        PieceId aPieceId;
        int aValue;
        if (pMaximizing)
        {
            aPieceId = mAIPiece;
        }
        else
        {
            aPieceId = mHumanPiece;
        }

        PieceId aResult = CheckWin(pRowId, pColId, aPieceId, pPosInfo, true);

        if (mScoreInfo.TryGetValue(aResult, out aValue))
        {

            return aValue;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Undefined Variable in PieceId enum");
            return 0;
        }

    }

public PieceId CheckWin(int pRowId, int pColId, PieceId pPieceId, AIPosInfo[,] pPosArray, bool pAI)//The functionalities for the last parameter was removed because it wasn't needed. 
    {

        var aPosArray = pPosArray;

        bool aHorMatch = true;
        bool aVerMatch = true;
        bool aDiag1Match = true;
        bool aDiag2Match = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < BoardSetup.mInstance.mDegree; i++)
        {

            if (aPosArray[pRowId, i].mFilledPiece != pPieceId)
            {
                aHorMatch = false;
                //Debug.LogError("Not Horizontal");
            }

            if (aPosArray[i, pColId].mFilledPiece != pPieceId)
            {
                aVerMatch = false;
                //Debug.LogError("Not Vertical");
            }

            if (aPosArray[i, i].mFilledPiece != pPieceId)
            {
                aDiag1Match = false;
                //  Debug.LogError("Not Diagonal 1");
            }

            if (aPosArray[i, (BoardSetup.mInstance.mDegree - 1) - i].mFilledPiece != pPieceId)
            {
                aDiag2Match = false;
                //Debug.LogError("Not Diagonal 2");
            }
        }

        if (aHorMatch ||
           aVerMatch ||
           aDiag1Match ||
           aDiag2Match)
        {

            return pPieceId;
        }
        else
        {
            var aBoardInfo = BoardSetup.mInstance.mPosInfo;
            bool aCheckFill = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < aBoardInfo.Count; i++)
            {
                if (aBoardInfo[i].mFilledPiece == PieceId.Empty)
                {
                    aCheckFill = false;
                }
            }

            if (aCheckFill)
            {

                Debug.Log("Game Tied");

                return PieceId.Draw;
            }
        }

        return PieceId.Playing;

    }
```

Comment: if is looping infinetly it means that the exit conditional which seems to be "if (pDepth >= mDepthLimit && aScore != -5)" is not working, is your CheckScore acting correctly? Is mDepthLimit const?

Comment: I checked that..the depth keeps increasing until 7, after that it increases and decreases back and forth. As for the aScore value, it returns infinity. Whereas according to logic, it should return 1 for AI victory, -1 for human victory, 0 for draw or -5 for game still playing.

Comment: The depth keeps increasing until the first time the board is filled, after which, when the values start returning from the function, and the board starts emptying, it gets messed up.

Comment: I have to add, it doesn't even get inside the matrix loop, directly returning infinity, the way values were initialized.

Comment: two questions, your "aCheckEmpty" and "aTest" variables are assigned but not used? and does your jaggedArray allways squared?

Comment: Ignore aCheckEmpty, it was for testing purposes. And yes, the Jagged Array is always square. At present it is only 3x3.

Comment: are you specting that "i" and "j" variables are passed by reference, or by value?

Comment: I thought i and j would be passed by value as default. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Comments:
1) where is your CheckScore code?

2) that conditional is very hard to understand, I had to read your comments to understand that -5 is a signal for still playing. I would rather have a bool isPlaying 

3) your human and AI evaluation loops are almost identical except a bool to keep track of human vs AI.

So my half-answer: clean-up and refactor your code and you will actually fix your bug I bet!

Comment: Yes, they are passed by value, just checking (cause we don't have the CheckScore method). What @ErikBethke says it's true, will be better for us to have that CheckScore method, and will be better for you to clean-up the code a little ^^'

Comment: Posted. It does make my question bigger though. So that's a trade off.

Comment: `it should return 1 for AI victory, -1 for human victory, 0 for draw or -5 for game still playing` - this last thing will mess you up, I think. Guaranteed win or loss (end of game) should have greater magnitude than any other score - otherwise a win seen on a deeper ply (half-move) can be hidden by (score less than) an inferior move on a different branch.

Comment: So what are you suggesting? The AI victory as the largest score,  and the terminal condition is any value that is not -5. or if the depth is reached.

Comment: You might use high values, like 10000 and -10000 for human and computer wins, respectively.

Comment: Urm..I didn't think it would have mattered. The score isn't adding up. So what difference does it make if the value is 10000/-10000 or 1/-1?

Comment: By the way, I added the initial function at the first block of code for further reference.

Comment: It matters if you return -5 and expect it to mean something other than "worse than if we lost".

Comment: It never actually returns -5, the terminal condition explicitly states that recursion should continue if the returning value is -5 and only return if it is -1 or 1 or 0.

Comment: Or in this case, +/- Infinity too..which is what this function seems to return after filling all available slots of the board and emptying the bottom three slots.